# Atmel studio assembly : Square root of an 8-bit number

Tags: assembly, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

I am working with ATmega328P in Atmel Studio and I have to make a function/algorithm, that takes an 8-bit number and calculates the square root of it. The result has to be given in two registers, one for the integer part and another for the decimal part.

I was thinking about this: the root has to be somewhere between the number given and 0 (or 1). So I would lsr (divide by 2) and it would check if it's greater, lesser or equal, and then try again with more precision, and so it would get more and more precise.

The problem is that the integer won't be correct and that I don't know how to put it to code, because I'm a new to assembly. I can also post what I made so far.

Thank you for any advice and help.

Comment: How about 256 bytes long look up table with results? (uhm, more like 512B long, because decimal part ... is it fixed point math 8:8? I guess) (and if you have only 256B for decimals, the whole part can be done sort of simply+slowly by one loop)

Comment: Sadly it's and assignment and I have to calculate it, otherwise that would be a viable option, but thanks for input.

Comment: Although I will do this as a last resort, if I don't figure it out.
(You suggest making a program that would compare the inserted number with 256 results, and end if it finds it right?)

Comment: it depends on how much complexity and precision you need. Because you can just do a brute force from 0 to 15 to cover the whole range of 8-bit unsigned number. It can be further be optimized by a binary search

Comment: No, you don't search through LUT (look up table), the input value works as address into it, let's say the result is 8:8 fixed point (i.e. for input 0x0A (10) you will return 0x0329 (809 = sqrt(10)*256 = 3.16227766...*256). So in your lookup table you would have at address 20..21 (input*2) bytes 0x0329. (sqrt(9) = 0x0300 in 8:8 fixed point) ... If you have spare 512B for the table, this is fastest way to calculate sqrt on something like 8b CPU, as it involves just calculating correct memory address (input*2).

Comment: Otherwise I would start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots ... the per-digit binary example looks reasonable, but I'm not sure if it can be extended to calculate decimal part obviously. If not, you have to treat input number as top-most 8 bits of 24 bit integer, integer square root of that is 8:8 fixed point result. (sqrt(0x010000) = 0x0100 = 1.0 ... and sqrt(0x0A0000) = 0x0329 = 3.16015625 or other way 0x0329*0x0329 = 0x09FC91 (almost 0A) ... 0x032A*0x32A = 0x0A02E4 (actually closer to proper result))

Comment: that is what a LUT is, you take a variable and use it as the index (address) into the table.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here.
Regarding precision it has to be until two "decimals" like this:
root (5)  = 2.2360...
    ldi r16, 0x05
    ((program))
    returned:
    r17 : r18= 0x02 : 0x17 ( because it's hex)

It doesnt matter beyond that.
It just has to be calculated, not through trial and error ( as in incrementing r18 (by 0.01) and trying again, or trying correct results)

Or maybe I don't understand what you're saying. Sorry :/

Comment: ARGH... that's not 8:8 fixed point, that's something... not usable in real world, but good for assignment. In the 8:8 fixed point the second 8 bits (second register) is amount of 1/256, i.e. 0 = 0.00, 0x80 = 0.5, 0x29 = 0.16015625, 0xFF = 0.99609375 ... which is directly usable in further math calculations. Your 0x17 = 23 is better for output, but as it is amount of 1/100, it is wasting bits (less precision), and difficult to reuse for further binary math calculations.  You should have specified that in question, how that values are split into the registers.

Comment: To extend the input for integer sqrt for the 1/100 variant (to produce 8b whole + 0-99 decimal) you can do input*100*100 (for 10: sqrt(10*100*100) = sqrt(100000) = 316 => then split this to hundreds (3x 100) and 0-99 remainder (16), and result is pair [3, 16] ... lot more ugly calculations in binary world, 8:8 fixed is unfortunately much more powerful and elegant representation in binary world, and simpler to achieve, as all the multiplications/divisions are by bit shifting, while *100 and /100 are difficult.

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry for the confusion and thank you for your patience.
As I said I'm a newbie.
I think it could be returned in 0x23, but I'm not sure If I understand everything you said.

Comment: I didn't use 0x23 anywhere. You are still missing what n:m "fixed point" math is. For 0.23 in 8:8 fixed point you would use value 58 or 59 (0x3A or 0x3B), because 58/256 = 0.2265625 and 59/256 = 0.23046875, so these two are closest representations of value 0.23 by binary 1/256 values summed. ... I.e. if you have 16 bits, and split it 8:8, then 0x0100 (256) is 1.0. Because 256/256 = 1.0 ... (np with patience/newbie, just don't panic if I sound hostile, focus on factual content)

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure I have to work with hex / binary, but then wouldn't I just do *256 instead of *100? ( with shifts or mul) or.. 
And in your explanation, how did you get from sqrt(100 000) to 316?

Comment: Oh, I think that now I understand what you mean by fixed number. Thanks.
In this assignment I don't think it matters so I'll do the simplest way.
I'll try to do the Digit-by-digit calculation method.
This I recognize, because the professor tried to explain it to me, but that's hard to do in ten minuted so I didn't really understand it, and now you recommended it. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programmer-s-toolbox/4219659/Integer-Square-Roots

Comment: This seems very helpful, but the images with all the flowcharts and formulas don't display (404). Is it just me?

Comment: @Ped7g that format is used in many areas when you only need to display the value instead of doing further maths with it, like [this sensor output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44084276/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness (or useless show of), here is how to do the task with whole numbers only, without multiplication, by linear search (which should be in most of the cases for 0-15 values still faster, than binary search with multiplication).

```
root = -1
square = 0
addValue = 1
while (square <= input) {
    square += addValue
    addValue += 2
    ++root
}
; here root == trunc(sqrt(input))
```

So, if you would not need the decimal part, this would be enough, or if you would be allowed to use at least 256B long LUT for decimal parts, together with this.

Writing proper decimal sqrt with 8 bit integer registers is actually quite some work, and I'm not going to take away all the fun from you. :P ..

Check various algorithms, and don't forget that limited range of decimals can be turned into integers by multiplication by some "base_exp" value.

I.e. values from 0.00 to 15.99 can be turned into 11 bit integers by doing *100 (0-1599), and that sqrt of (100*100) is 100, so by input*10000 you will get values 0-2550000 (needs at least 22 bits, round it up to 24b), then doing integer square root of that will give you result *100 (and fits into 11 bits), so you can further split it into two values by dividing by 100.

This may look simple for human, but in real world when doing decimal calculations with 8/16b registers it was often done by this principle, but instead powers of two were used, i.e. *256*256, which can be done simply by shifting value 16 bits left. And division by 256 is shifting values by 8 to right.

So for that per digit method with binary numbers you will need to create 24 bit addition/subtraction/shifter pieces of code. Then the input number is top-most 8 bits of 24 bit number. (i.e. input value `10` => `(10<<16) == 0x0A0000`) => simple shifting. Calculate sqrt of that (0x0329 or 0x032A, depends if you manage to do just truncating, or rounding at the last bit), and that's it, the result will surely fit into 12 bits, and upper 4 are the whole part 0-15, the lower 8 bits is decimals in "amount of 1/256" value (0x29/256 = 0.16015625). Which can be again split by simple shifting/anding, i.e. no mul/div operation needed.

So it will be still lot of work, but it's reasonable (doing 24 bit multiplication/division on 8b CPU is lot more pain, than doing add/sub/shifting extension). And explain why you opted for 4:8 [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) format of result, to use full 8 bits of precision from the decimal part of result and make it simpler for further binary calculations. (in 8:8 fixed point 0.5 = 0x0080 ... try to add that and see what happens: 0x0080 + 0x0080 = 0x0100 = 1.0 without any complex tampering with result .. that's how we did low-precision decimal calculations on 8 bit CPUs, for example for sin/cos effects, also multiplication/division is simpler, again for 0.5: 0x0080 * 0x0080 = (0x4000>>8) = 0x0040 = 0.25).